# Adding an item to a dropdownlist which is in another partial view without refreshing the view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net mvc and I am facing this issue with dropdownlist now.
Sorry if I am asking a stupid question.

I have  a main View `AbcView` which is bound to a Controller `AbcController` which passes an `AbcModel` to the view.

I have 2 partial views inside this `AbcView` which are loaded on button clicks.

Inside the second partial view, I have this code :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.TrajectoryName, new SelectList(@Model.Trajectories, "Value", "Text"),
                        new { @class = "dropdown-leftandright", id = drpTrajectory" })
```

Inside the first partial view, I have some data which is being added to database on some button click like this :

```
function deleteAction(trajID) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/AbcView/DeleteAction",
    data: JSON.stringify({ deleteTraj: trajID }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
        // I want to update the drpTrajectory dropdownlist here
    },
    error: function (e) {
        return "error";
    }
});        
}
```

My issue is I want to access the `drpTrajectory` in second partial view inside this function. I want to add some item to this particular drop down list. 
I tried to access the dropdownlist by using `$('#drpTrajectory')` and tried to add an item. But it is failing.

I tried to add data like this

```
$('#drpTrajectory ').add(val(data.x).text(data.y));
```

`data` will be a member from a `IEnumerable<SomeClass> dataList` and `SomeClass` contains `id` and `name` which could be the value and text respectively.

I am already updating the model data during the button click ie  `@Model.Trajectories` is getting updated.

So please help me to add an item to this dropdownlist which is in second partial view from my first partial view without refreshing the entire view.
Any idea?

Comment: Show how you tried to add it. And what does `data` contain? (to add an option its `$('#drpTrajectory').append($('<option></option>').val(data.x).text(data.y));`)

Comment: What does `<option></option>` mean? I understood the value and text part. I tried something like this `$('#drpTrajectory ').add(val(data.x).text(data.y));`. @StephenMuecke

Comment: You should show that in the question so an answer can be given, and indicate what `data` is and what properties of it you use to add the new option

Comment: I have edited. Please check now @StephenMuecke

Comment: Give me 15 min and I'll add an answer (you also have a few other things that can be improved in your code) - but you have noted that `data` is a serialized `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` - are you wanting to add multiple options to the dropdownlist?

Comment: Yes I am trying to add multiple options to it. Thanks a lot for your time. I tried as per your first comment and it is working perfectly.

Comment: An answer has already been added, but I'll still add one shortly to explain the other issues with your code

Comment: Yes, sure. Thanks. Please help to clear the list too before adding each item again as it is adding duplicate entries to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your method is returning a collection of objects, then to create and append an option to a `<select>` you need

```
var select = $('#drpTrajectory') // cache it
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("DeleteAction", "AbcView")',
    data: { deleteTraj: trajID },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        select.empty() // if you need to remove the existing options
        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
            // Create an option element
            var option = $('<option></option>').val(item.id).text(item.name);
            // append it to the select element
            select.append(option);
        })
    },
    ....
});
```

Side notes

1. Always use `@Url.Action()` to ensure that your url's are correctly
   generated
2. There is no need to `stringify() the data and then add the`
   contentType` option
3. Your controller method should be returning a collection of anonymous
   objects containing just the 2 properties you need (there is no point
   sending back extra data that's not use)

   ```
   var data = dataList.Select(x => new { id = x.id, name = x.name });
   return Json(data)
   ```
4. Your use of `new SelectList(@Model.Trajectories, "Value", "Text")`
   suggests that the property `Trajectories` is already
   `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`. If that is the case, there is no
   point creating an identical `SelectList` from the original one, so
   just use

   ```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.TrajectoryName, Model.Trajectories, new { @class = "dropdown-leftandright", id = drpTrajectory" })
   ```
5. The `DropDownListFor()` method is already creating
   `id="TrajectoryName"` so there is no real need to overwrite it by
   using `new { id = drpTrajectory" }`

Comment: Looking at your code, I'm guessing that all your really wanting to do is to remove one option form the `<select>` - if that is the case, its not really necessary to return the data from creating a new list of options - you can just remove one option from the existing `<select>`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thanks for your time. So much info. Since I am a beginner, it will be helpful to me. A doubt regarding point 4 : If we are binding to IEnumerable<SelectListItem> then there is no need to specify the value and text like this, right? `new SelectList(@Model.Trajectories, "Value", "Text")`

Comment: No. If your model property is `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Trajectories { get; set; }`, then just use `Model.Trajectories` for the 2nd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` - all that code is doing is creating another identical `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` - its just unnecesary extra overhead

Comment: I also recommend you stop polluting your markup with behavior and use [Unobtrusive JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (I assume you must currently have something like `<button onclick="deleteAction(this.id)" ...>`

Comment: Yes. It's something similar. Its a list item passing id on button click. So it is not a good practice to pass the ID to the js function?

Comment: You obviously still need to pass an the `ID`, but better practice is to use (say) `<button type="button" class="delete" data-trajID="@item.TrajectoryID">Delete</button>` and then the script becomes `$('.delete').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('trajID'); ..... `

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
 success: function (data) {
    // I want to update the drpTrajectory dropdownlist here
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        $('#drpTrajectory').append($('<option>', { 
             value: item.id,
             text : item.name 
        }));
    });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I already found a solution as per Stephen's comment.